# Is this SQLMap query is correct?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, sqlmap, waf

I am practicing on some vulnerable application, and I am asked to find an injection vulnerability with a payload. it states there is a common and simple filter in place. Then I need to extract the `flag` value from the `chlns` table.
So I use SQLmap to find it.

Please read below and correct me if I am wrong in any stage:

```
sqlmap -u 'http://www.site.com/game.php?name=sarah’ --dbs
```

When I run it, it asks that it is being redirected to facebook, and I press `n` to not do that. Then it continious and load 3 databases as such:

```
-- information_schema
-- chlns
-- people
```

on I run the following query:

```
sqlmap -u 'http://www.site.com/game.php?name=sarah’ -D chlns --tables
```

to get all the tables. After it starts running it gives the below error:

```
[ERROR] unable to retrieve the table names for any database
do you want to use common table existence check? [y/N/q] y
```

Then it asks for a file or use the default wordlist. Which I used the default option.
At the end it came up with a list of tables (13 overall) which then I used the below code for one of the sample table names:

```
sqlmap -u 'http://www.site.com/game.php?name=sarah’ -D chlns T- table --dump
```

this code asks for the same thing when i run it and want to run it through a worklist. each process takes a long time around 10/15 mins and each time it come up with an error like below:

```
HTTP error code: 414 (Request-URI Too Large) [*N times...
```

And i get nowhere. Am I doing anything wrong here? or is there any easier way?
the excercise mentiones there is a table called `chlns` but it seems `chlns` is a database instead. This could be the case as in another excercise `chlns` was the database and `one` was the name of the table that `flag` existed.

Is there any suggestions to make this process easier or any pro advice?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Generally challenges like this is to learn how to exploit SQL injection, not to learn how to run sqlmap. The tool has a tendency to turn most SQL injection vectors into time based sql which explains why it takes so long. I would recommend taking a stab at manual exploitation.

Comment: I think this sentence is key: "it states there is a common and simple filter in place". You may want to experiment with the sqlmap --tamper scripts.